# how to remove duplicate words (same words but different case) in text

Tags: text

I have a text file which contains a long list of words. Some of them are overlapped by means of case such as:

- Honesty
- honesty

I want to remove upper case and leave the lower one counted as one word. 
How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you wanting to write a program to do this?  Or do you just have one text file that needs to be edited once and you're just looking for a tool to help with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried and got it.

```
> cat test
Honesty
World
Hello
world
Hello
honesty

> sort -uf test
Hello
Honesty
World

> sort -uf test | tr A-Z a-z
 hello
 honesty
 world
```

Thanks for your helping mind.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read a word
2. Convert it to lower case
3. Check for duplicates with some sort of set/hashtable sort of thing.

For example, in C++, you could use something like this:

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctype.h>

struct lowercase { 
    std::string operator()(std::string const &s) const { 
        std::string ret(s);
        std::transform(&s[0], &s[s.length()-1], &ret[0], tolower);
        return ret;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::set<std::string> items;

    std::transform(
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin), 
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(), 
        std::inserter(items, items.begin()),
        lowercase());

    std::copy(items.begin(), items.end(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```